# I have given overflow button on right side after clicking on 1 menu item it should go to that activity but I am unable to jump on that activity

Tags: java, android

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homeactivity);
        list(getIntent().getExtras().getString("JSON_Object"));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.changepwd:
     //                Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Change_Password_Activity.class);
     //                this.startActivity(myIntent);
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.aishwarya.registerlogin.change_password_activity"));
            Toast.makeText(this, "You selected change pwd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.setuname:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You selected set username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.setdp:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You selected set profile picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. And: you are asking a **java android** question. All those other tags for other languages are absolutely meaningless!

Comment: @aishwaryak make sure whether u have added the action "com.example.aishwarya.registerlogin.change_password_activity" for paswordActivity in manifest, if you have added it, then make sure whether u have given category for the Activity as CATEGORY_DEFAULT

Comment: @Hasif Seyd yes I have added it but still its not working,there is no warning,no error,even application is also not crashing but its not going to next activity.does I have to write anything in onCreate ? so that it will go to onCreateOptionMenu.whle debugging I found that it is not going to OnCreateOptionMenu

Comment: do you use Toolbar?

Comment: @hosseinAmini  I haven't used toolbar.I am beginner to android. should I use toolbar ?

Comment: @aishwaryak Yeah. actually you have to use Toolbar instead of action bar. You can learn it here: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use the code that you have commented:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Change_Password_Activity.class);
 startActivity(myIntent);
```

Make sure that the name of the activity you want to inicialize has the name "**Change_Password_Activity**"

Comment: @ Catarina Ferreira I am selecting change password menu item

Comment: Thats because its not going inside that

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch(id){
            case R.id.changepwd:
     //                Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Change_Password_Activity.class);
     //                this.startActivity(myIntent);
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.aishwarya.registerlogin.change_password_activity"));
            Toast.makeText(this, "You selected change pwd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.setuname:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You selected set username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.setdp:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You selected set profile picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }
        return true;

    }
```